# Yarn workspaces and yarn link

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg, lerna

I have a workspaces project like so:

```
/project
  - package.json
    /packages
       /project-a
          package.json
       /project-b
          package.json
```

`project-b` depends on `project-a`.
Inside workspaces everything is running fine. Now I want to use `project-b` inside another (new) npm project. Normally `yarn link` would work, but because of the dependency on `project-a` this will not work. Is there a correct way to do this?

I've tried `yalc` and `publising to npm` which both work, but I like to know if there's an alternate lerna/yarn/npm solution I am not aware of.

Comment: For answers, I would like to see a `yarn link` example for yarn 2, as to how yarn is supposed to implement local package reading, without using external libraries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using verdaccio for this now; https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio 
Verdaccio allows to create a local npm registry.

Comment: I'm curious, why did you choose `verdaccio` over `yalc`? `verdaccio` seems like a solid solution (given it's being used by CRA, Gatsby, Storybook, Babel...) but `yalc` seems like it would be a better fit for simpler use cases, i.e. a "better yarn link" that avoids the hassle to set up a local registry.